# Settings not getting saved when updating in NetworkManager

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn

On `Ubuntu 22.04`, i am trying to update my VPN settings but the settings don't get saved, however if i create a new record for example, if i create a new VPN connection then the settings get saved.

[image]

however, once the record has been created I am unable to modify it and the settings don't get applied.

for example, in the above screenshot, i created a VPN which got saved correctly but later i tried to update the settings `Make available to other users` but this does not get applied / saved and i see the checkbox as unchecked when i open the settings after updating.

Any help on how to fix this would be great, Thanks.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: ubuntu version is `22.04`

Comment: Have you reviewed any system/application logs to see if there are any errors getting generated when you attempt to manage your network connections (`sudo journalctl -b -u NetworkManager` would be a good place to start)? Also, it might be useful to try running from the command line to watch for interesting output: `nm-connection-editor`.

Comment: 1) Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<your-vpn-connection>.nmconnection`. 2) Set `permissions` param empty string like: `permissions=`. 3) Save file. 4) Restart NetworkManager: `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`